# Inno Setup always starts PowerShell in 32-bit mode in Pascal Script code

Tags: windows, installation, inno-setup, pascalscript, wow64

I want to use PowerShell (64-bit version) in the `ssPostInstall` step of my Inno Setup, but it always opens a 32-bit PowerShell.

As you can see in my script my Inno Setup is configured as 64-bit application.
When I start the setup I can see in the Task Manager that it is running as a 32-bit application

[image]

Also the PowerShell which will be opened, is in 32 bit-mode.

[image]

Here is my Inno Stup script:

```pascal
[Setup]
ArchitecturesAllowed=x64
ArchitecturesInstallIn64BitMode=x64
PrivilegesRequired=admin

[Code]
Procedure CurStepChanged(CurrentStep:TSetupStep);
var
  i, ResultCode, ErrorCode: Integer;
  findRec: TFindRec;
  isInstallationCmdSuccessful: Boolean;  
  folderNameOfUpdateIni: String;
  ReturnCode: Boolean;

begin  
  if CurrentStep = ssPostInstall then begin
      Log('Starting post install steps, calling install.ps1');
      ReturnCode := ShellExec('open', ExpandConstant('{sys}\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe'), '', '', SW_SHOWNORMAL, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ErrorCode);
      if (ReturnCode = True) then
        Log('post install returned true')
      else
        Log('post install returned false');


      Log('Starting post install steps, calling install.ps1');
      ReturnCode := ShellExec('open', ExpandConstant('{syswow64}\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe'), '', '', SW_SHOWNORMAL, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ErrorCode);
      if (ReturnCode = True) then
        Log('post install returned true')
      else
        Log('post install returned false');
  end;
end;
```

How can I force Inno Setup to open a 64-bit PowerShell?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to allow Pascal Script code functions to use 64-bit `System32` files, use [`EnableFsRedirection` function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_enablefsredirection) to [disable WOW64 file system redirection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/file-system-redirector).

And you also cannot use `ShellExec`, you need to use [`Exec` function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_exec) instead.

```pascal
OldState := EnableFsRedirection(False);
try
  ReturnCode :=
    Exec('powershell.exe', '', '', SW_SHOWNORMAL, ewWaitUntilTerminated,
         ErrorCode);
finally
  EnableFsRedirection(OldState);
end;
```

---

Btw, `ArchitecturesInstallIn64BitMode` does not/cannot make Inno Setup run as 64-bit application. Inno Setup is 32-bit application, no matter what.

Comment: Thank you - I'd been struggling to find this for days